# is function an object? Why console.log does not show inspectable Object?

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = function () {};
foo.a = "an attribute";  // set attribute to prove foo is an object
console.log(foo)  // log shows: function () {};
```

I thought function foo is an object, but why console.log in Chrome shows `"function () {}"` rather than an inspectable Object? Is there anyway to show inspectable Object when logging a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `console.log(foo)`, the console builds a non normalized display (it's not part of EcmaScript). In most cases (but not for basic objects) it calls the `toString` function of the argument (but does more work, like adding quotes to string, setting a color, offering object browsing, etc.).

The `toString` function of a function simply prints the code.

If you want to see all properties, you might do

```
console.dir(foo);
```

or ([at least on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject_object))

```
console.log("%O", foo);
```

You'd see the same phenomenon with other objects having a dedicated `toString` function.

For example :

```
var a = new Number(3);
a.b = 4;
console.log(a); // logs just 3
console.dir(a); // lets you see b
```

Comment: I don't think it calls `toString`. The console just formats the value how it sees fit. After all `console.log({})` does not show `[object Object]` (at least in Chrome).

Comment: @FelixKling In fact it depends... I'm looking at it. I've also tested `Object.prototype.toString.apply(foo)`

Comment: wow, thanks for console.log("%O", foo);, never know that there is a %O

Comment: OK, I meant to say it does not *only* call `toString` ;) For example, for arrays Chrome shows the `undefined x 2` shorthand as well.

Comment: @FelixKling I wasn't saying you were wrong. I was both trying many cases and trying to find a general formulation.

Comment: just know about `console.dir`, I use `console.log` all the time in a thought that there's some magic inside. From now, I should use `console.dir` whenever I need to inspect object. As in some circumstance in code, using `console.log` didn't show all of its properties like it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.dir()` to see the `a`

```
>>>>console.log(foo);
function()
>>>>console.dir(foo);
a            "an attribute"
prototype    Object { }
```

Answer (score 0):

dystroy is right. function is an object whose toString prints the code.

```
console.log(foo.a);
```

would do the trick