# console.log and valueOf

Tags: javascript, node.js

After trying to solve an one little task I was a bit confused by the strange behavior of the `console.log` function. I expected that `console.log` will use the `valueOf` function as a converter of the object to the primitive value. But I was wrong...

It's better to explain with an example.

```
Number.prototype.sum = function sum(val) {
    var newVal = this + val;
    var f = sum.bind(newVal);
    f.valueOf = f.toString = function () {
        return newVal;
    };
    return f;
};

var numb = 50;
var res = numb.sum(10)(2)(2);
console.log(res);
alert(res);
```

I expected get the `64` in both of `alert` and `console.log`.  But it's works only for `alert` as you can see at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yhrnrnL/

In the case of `console.log` I always getting something like "function b()" instead of `64`. Can someone explain me why it happens and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: That's how `console.log` works.

Comment: `alert` accepts a string and will convert its argument to a string if it doesn’t get one. `console.log` accepts any object and inspects it intelligently.

Comment: @minitech Can I affect to the `console.log` and output `64` instead of "function b()" without redefinition of `console.log`?

Comment: Neither *alert* or *console.log* are covered by a specification (ECMA-262 doesn't define any input or output), so you get what you get. While *alert* is reasonably consistent, *console.log* is very much implementation dependent.

Comment: You can - implement and apply a patch to your JS engine.

Comment: @uzumaxy: You can use `console.log('%d', res);`. That’s not really the same thing, though. Why not convert it manually in any other way if that’s acceptable, or stop overriding `valueOf` and just get a property specifically when you want the result?

Comment: @minitech Thanks for your answer. I'll try explain why I can't change console.log and why I had override valueOf method.

It was interview task.I was not allowed to change a code on line with console.log function. I made it work only for alert, but wasn't able do the same for console.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript `alert` expects a string and if it isn't provided a string it will attempt to convert that value into a string.

To get your console.log to work you can simply use the `parseInt()` function like so

```
Number.prototype.sum = function sum(val) {
    var newVal = this + val;
    var f = sum.bind(newVal);
    f.valueOf = f.toString = function () {
        return newVal;
    };
    return f;
};

var numb = 50;
var res = numb.sum(10)(2)(2);
console.log(parseInt(res));
alert(res);
```

Comment: There is no other way?

Comment: @uzumaxy Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064312/is-function-an-object-why-console-log-does-not-show-inspectable-object